# Not able to run FFmpegFrameGrabber with HLS stream

Tags: java, javacv

I need to use FFmpegFrameGrabber for converting a live stream http livestreaming to images and audio segments of 10 seconds. I am always getting grabbedimage null in the following code. I need some help on using javacv to download live streams.

```
URL streamUrl = new URL("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4");

URLConnection connection = streamUrl.openConnection();

InputStream is2 = connection.getInputStream();
FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(is2);
Frame grabbedImage = null;
grabber.start();
grabber.setFrameRate(grabber.getFrameRate());

Java2DFrameConverter c = new Java2DFrameConverter();
while ((grabbedImage = grabber.grab()) != null) {
    ImageIO.write(c.convert(grabbedImage), "png",
            new File("/mnt/test/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));
}
grabber.close();
```

Comment: Since you're only transcoding, it's probably easier to use the ffmpeg program like this: http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/apidocs/org/bytedeco/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.html

Comment: Thanks @SamuelAudet The example you gave is for a saved video on disk. Does FFmpegFrameGrabber work direct with a live stream like HLS ? currently getting error like "image == null!" with ImageIO.write line. Is there anyway to avoid that?

Comment: Yes, it works with HTTP, etc URLs as well.